# Wrong outputs from dll c++ to vba

Tags: c++, excel, vba

I created a DLL in C++ and I call it through Excel VBA. The DLL includes a function with 3 arguments. When I run the function in Excel, I observe the following:

- In the first `if` statement, the function returns zero
- In the second and third statements, the function returns the right value

I cannot understand why it happens. Could you please help me?

**C++ code**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include  <fstream>
#include  <istream>

using namespace std;

double _stdcall
Tables(int &a, int &b, double &c)
{
    double q[125];
    if (b == 1)
    {
        ifstream inFile("path");    
        for (int Pntr = 1; Pntr < 126; Pntr++)
        {
            inFile >> q[Pntr - 1];
        }
        return q[a] * c;
    }
    else if (b == 2)
    {
        ifstream inFile("path");
        for (int Pntr = 1; Pntr < 126; Pntr++)
        {
            inFile >> q[Pntr - 1];
        }
        return q[a];
    }else if (b == 3)
    {
        ifstream inFile("path");
        for (int Pntr = 1; Pntr < 126; Pntr++)
        {
            inFile >> q[Pntr - 1];
        }
        return q[a];
    }
    return 1000;
}
```

**VBA code**

```vb
Public Declare PtrSafe Function propTable Lib "dll path" (a As Long, b As Long, c As Double) As Double

Public Function EAE1990m(a As Long, b As Long, c As Double) As Double
    EAE1990m = propTable(a, b, c)
End Function
```

Comment: Does the same happen when you call it from C++?

Comment: Do nto know c++ but the only difference that i see is `return q[a] * c;` What is the value of `c`?

Comment: Also check what is the value of `q[a]`. One of them is `0`

Comment: It doesn't happen the same when call it via C++.

Comment: The logical conclusion of your two observations is that `c == 0` for the first case.

Comment: Right, however if I initialize the variale (etc c = 5), the output is correct for all the cases.

Comment: You didn't initialize c but multiply with it? What you expect to happen? It has uninitialized value (likely random). That explains the difference in behavior when called from VBA.

Comment: I initialized the argument c but the behavior is the same.